# Dissable Collisions for a Unity 2D Object

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, layer

At the moment I am programming a Unity 2D game. When the game is running the cars start moving and respawn continuously. The ball will be used to throw it against the cars. I used Box Collider in order to give the cars a base to drive on, but now the ball is unable to get to the lane on bottom because it is blocked by the upper lane.

I want to disable the collision between my ball and other game objects in order to enable the possibility to differ between the lanes, but I don't know how? I hoped I can differentiate it using layers but I wasn´t able to fix my problem. Has anyone of you an idea, how to solve my problem. I will attach a picture to improve your understanding of my issue. 
[Example of the scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vGzO.jpg)

Comment: 1st.  When you tried Layers did you also modify the Layer Collision Matrix?  2nd. Could you "tag" the ball and test for the tag on collision?

Answer (score 0):

Put the ball on a different layer (let's say a layer named "Ball") and the lane on a different layer (let's say a layer named "Lanes"). Then go to Edit->Project Settings, click on Physics 2D and uncheck the checkbox which intersects the Ball layer with the Lanes layer. This will prevent collisions between the items on the 2 layers.

Answer (score 0):

In the description you state your object is using a `Box Collider` ... for 2D you would rather want to use a `BoxCollider2D`.

As mentioned you can disable the collision between two specific Layers via the `Edit` → `Project Settings` → `Physics 2D` → [Layer Collision Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Physics2DManager.html)

[image]

You can also (and this might be interesting for you as well) disable the collisions between objects of the same layer here.

Maybe not your exact use-case but this way you can also e.g. ignore collisions between all enemies but still allow each enemy to collide with the floor and user objects.

---

Alternatively you can also do the same on runtime using [`Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision.html) and e.g. also temporarily enable and disable these collisions

```c#
Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(layer1Index, layer2Index, ignore);
```

or even only ignore collisions between two specific colliders using [`Physics2D.IgnoreCollision`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.IgnoreCollision.html)

```c#
 Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(objectA.GetComponent<Collider2D>(), objectB.GetComponent<Collider2D>(), ignore);
```

where `ignore` is a `bool`.

Comment: thanks for your very detailed description. Helped me a lot